# Can't update TextView in a Custom Dialog from an event in another Custom Dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two Custom Dialogs. Dialog A which is like a form that takes in two fields. And Dialog B which acts as a Validation Popup letting the user know if the value is a duplicate value that is already in use or an Unknown value. The user can edit the field in Dialog B, which when he presses the save button, it should update the text field in Dialog A.

Dialog A:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //return customview for the fragment
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AMEditSampleDialogLayout, container, false);
        tagEdit = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tagEdit);
        yieldEdit = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.yieldEdit);
        missedYield = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.yieldMissed);
        cancel = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cancel);
        save = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.save);
    }

    public void TagConfirmListener(string tag, bool forceDuplicate)
    {
        this.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {

            // When I debug here, I can see the value passed back but didn't update the EditText.
            view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tagEdit).Text = tag;
        });
        tagValid = true;
        autoCompleteOptions.Add(tag);
    }
```

Dialog B:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //return customview for the fragment
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ConfirmCorrectTagDialog, container, false);
        tagEdit = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tagEdit);
        unit = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.unit);
        titleText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titleText);
        titleBackground = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.titleBackground);
        save = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.save);
        fixLater = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.fixLater);
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //remove title area
        Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); //dismiss window on touch outside

        tagEdit.Text = tag;
        titleText.Text = title;
        unit.Text = unitPassed;

        save.Click += delegate
        {
          this.CloseAndConfirm();
        }


    }

    private void CloseAndConfirm()
    {
        callback.TagConfirmListener(tagEdit.Text, fix.Checked);
        Dismiss();
    }

    public interface TagConfirmListener
    {
        void TagConfirmListener(string tag, bool force);
    }
```

I don't know why it won't update and even tried to run the UI thread to change it and I know the value is passing back to Dialog A.

Any help would be appreciated as my mind is boggled.

Comment: Does it a FragmentDialog? Would you mind to provide a demo for me?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT - I actually just finished the parent dialog through the callback listener. Did the job and removed more clicks for the user which is a win-win. But thanks for getting back to me :)

Comment: Maybe you can provide an answer, so it will help other people, happy code!